# Livecode - HTTP POST request

Tags: http, post, livecode

I'm trying to send a `HTTP POST` request in Livecode to a webservice.

This is the code in Livecode:

```
put 8 into tId
put the text of field "image_text" into tBlop
put tBlop into field "image_text"
put "id=" & tId & "&blop=" & base64Encode(tBlop) & "&pic=" &tBlop into tArgList
post tArgList to URL "http://www.example.com/api_donation/blop2"
put it into tFormResults
```

The webservice is written in `PHP` using the Slim framework

```
$id = $app->request->post('id');
$blop = $app->request->post('blop');
$pic = $app->request->post('pic');

// decode image
$blop = base64_decode($blop);
$db = getDB();
$sql = "INSERT INTO picture (id, blop, pic) VALUES ($id, $blop, $pic)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
//execute sql statement
$res = $stmt->execute($data);
```

However when the image is inserted in the db and I try to get it in Livecode, the image stored in the db is not a valid image.

Is the reason for this error the encoding? Do I need to change some settings in the db (e.g. `utf-8`)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: when you say 'I try to get it in Livecode' - what are you trying ?

Comment: Why are you sending the tBlop twice? Sending it as base64 should be OK but sending it as raw data will probably break if it is image data. According to the standard all posted data must be url-encoded if you don't change the content-type

Comment: @splash21 I am trying to download the picture in Livecode from the database. However even when I compare the encoded code stored in the database it is not identical with the encoded code generated in Livecode. Is there an encoding problem in the database?

Comment: @hliljegren I've sent it twice in order to check whether it works without the encoding, but as you said it, sending the raw data breaks the image.

Answer (score 0):

The properties **imageData** (binary) or **text** (ASCII) of an image are livecode properties regarding what is shown on the screen. They aren't bmp, jpg, png or any other format.

If you need to create a valid format, you need the **export** command.

See http://livecode.wikia.com/wiki/Export